# XMPP Blocking Delegate

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am working on the block feature for `XMPPUsers` using `XMPPBlocking` unit. While I am successfully able to block and unblock users using the `blockJID:` and `unblockJID` APIs of XMPP blocking unit, I am interested in a few delegate methods of `XMPPBlockingDelegate`. But `XMPPBlockingDelegate` does not have a delegate property to which my custom object can conform. So in essence how do I listen to the `XMPPBlockingDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. Hope this helps somebody. Forgot to mention I am working on an iOS app using the XMPP library. The `XMPPStream` essentially uses a multicast delegate. Any client interested in delegates likes `XMPPRosterDelegate,XMPPRoomDelegate,XMPPMUCDelegate,XMPPStreamDelegate` needs to add itself as a delegate to the stream using `- (void)addDelegate:(id)delegate delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)delegateQueue`. Hope this helps somebody